# Null pointer when reading XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, w3c

I am trying to get the all the authors from my xml file in jave here is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<map>
<authors>
    <author>testasdas</author>
    <author>Test</author>
</authors>
</map>
```

Here is the code I'm using in Java

```
public static List<String> getAuthors(Document doc) throws Exception {
    List<String> authors = new ArrayList<String>();
    Element ed = doc.getDocumentElement();
    if (notExists(ed, "authors")) throw new Exception("No authors found");
    Node coreNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("authors").item(0);
    if (coreNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element coreElement = (Element) coreNode;
        NodeList cores = coreElement.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < cores.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = cores.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element e = (Element) node;
                String author = e.getElementsByTagName("author").item(i).getTextContent();
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("here");
                authors.add(author);
            }
        }
    }
    return authors;
}
```

I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error when I try run the code but I'm not sure why.

> 09.04 17:05:24 [Server] SEVERE at com.dcsoft.arenagames.map.XMLHandler.getMapData(XMLHandler.java:42)
>   09.04 17:05:24 [Server] SEVERE at com.dcsoft.arenagames.map.XMLHandler.getAuthors(XMLHandler.java:73)
>   09.04 17:05:24 [Server] SEVERE java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Where is the full stacktrace?

Comment: `Try.. catch` -> stack trace ?

Comment: Which is line 73 of XMLHandler.java?

Comment: You should add missing information in the initial question, not in comments ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code is indexing the `<author>` nodelist using `i`, which counts all children of the `<authors>` tag, some of which are not `<author>` elements. When `item(i)` returns `null`, you get a NPE when you try to call `getTextContent()`. You also don't need to do all that navigation (which looks kind of suspicious, and is certainly confusing). Try this instead:

```
public static List<String> getAuthors(Document doc) throws Exception {
    List<String> authors = new ArrayList<String>();
    NodeList authorNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("author");
    for (int i = 0; i < authorNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        String author = authorNodes.item(i).getTextContent();
        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("here");
        authors.add(author);
    }
    return authors;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working but why do I not have to direct from the top <authors> tag?

Comment: @DCSoftware - because you can collect all the `<author>` tags directly from the document root. When you call `getElementsByTagName` for a node, it searches the entire tree rooted at that node, not just the children.

Answer (score 1):

To find the cause of a java.lang.NullPointerException put a breakpoint on the line the exception occurred at, 73 in this case and investigate the variables on that line.

My guess is that in you line of code:

```
String author = e.getElementsByTagName("author").item(i).getTextContent()
```

the variable `e` is the `author` element and hence why `e.getElementsByTagName("author")` returns a `null`.

Comment: If there are no `<author>` nodes under `e`, `getElementsByTagName` will not return `null`; it will return an empty `NodeList`. The problem is that `item(i)` returns `null` if `i` is out of range.

Comment: Of course, I think the upshot is, the original code was a mess and your cleaned up version is what's needed.